# Can NaBH4 reduce acid chlorides to alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My professor says it reduces only aldehydes and ketones, but acid chlorides are generally more reactive than both of them.

Comment: @Zhe That question refers to Dibal-H reduction of acid chlorides

Answer (score 3):

This [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00397910903340645) reports the reduction of acyl halides to  alcohols with NaBH4/K2CO3 in dichloromethane/water at low temperature under phase transfer catalysis.

This [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0040403981800275) reports the reduction of acyl halides by sodium borohydride in dimethyl formamide to aldehydes.

The choice of solvent conditions is critical as acyl halides will react with most of the solvents that are commonly used with NaBH4.